# How to get closest time on more than 2 fields by using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just want to try get the closest datetime by using GROUP BY on more than 2 fields. But when I tried, the data got messy. I was using:

the data source is:

```
Start Time              Real End Time           Staff
2013-02-14 16:44:27     2013-02-14 18:44:27     P 
2013-02-14 16:44:08     2013-02-14 17:09:08     C
2013-02-14 16:42:51     2013-02-14 16:43:51     P
2013-02-14 16:31:26     2013-02-14 17:06:26     V
2013-02-14 16:04:02     2013-02-14 16:34:02     C
```

when I was using:

```
SELECT staff AS name, start_time, max(real_end_time) AS work_end_time
FROM treatments 
WHERE date(real_end_time) = curdate()
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY work_end_time ASC
```

and I got:

```
name        start_time                work_end_time
V           2013-02-14 16:31:26       2013-02-14 17:06:26
C           2013-02-14 16:04:02       2013-02-14 17:09:08
P           2013-02-14 16:42:51       2013-02-14 18:44:27
```

Obviously the data was messed, the correct should be like:

```
name        start_time                work_end_time
V           2013-02-14 16:31:26       2013-02-14 17:06:26
C           2013-02-14 16:44:08       2013-02-14 17:09:08
P           2013-02-14 16:44:27       2013-02-14 18:44:27
```

for this, it killed plenty of my time, should you have good solution for this?
and also I tried:

```
SELECT staff AS name, start_time, max(real_end_time) AS work_end_time
FROM treatments 
WHERE date(real_end_time) = curdate()
GROUP BY name, start_time
ORDER BY work_end_time ASC
```

and I got:

```
name     start_time               work_end_time
C        2013-02-14 16:04:02      2013-02-14 16:34:02
P        2013-02-14 16:42:51      2013-02-14 16:43:51
V        2013-02-14 16:31:26      2013-02-14 17:06:26
C        2013-02-14 16:44:08      2013-02-14 17:09:08
P        2013-02-14 16:44:27      2013-02-14 18:44:27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT staff AS name, start_time, real_end_time AS work_end_time
FROM (  SELECT staff, start_time, real_end_time
        FROM treatments 
        WHERE date(real_end_time) = curdate()
        ORDER BY real_end_time ASC) AS h
GROUP BY name
```

You have to nest the query with the `ORDER BY` before using `GROUP BY`. Having `ORDER BY` as you do only handles the smashed together result, thus having a risk of faulty `name` and `start_time`

Comment: When I tried your SQL, I still got wrong, like this I got:
name    start_time             work_end_time
C       2013-02-14 16:04:02    2013-02-14 17:09:08
P       2013-02-14 16:42:51    2013-02-14 18:44:27
V       2013-02-14 16:31:26    2013-02-14 17:06:26

Comment: Try changing `ORDER BY real_end_time ASC` to `ORDER BY real_end_time DESC`

Comment: Sorry, You are right, but just now, I got wrong. thanks a lot

Comment: mysql is a little bit difference with ORACLE.